# why question is closed when it's already clear?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, specific-question

[Magento:2.3.1 How to remove loader from checkout when changing payment method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300868/magento2-3-1-how-to-remove-loader-from-checkout-when-changing-payment-method)

I want to remove loader once payment method change on checkout and it's so clear in question why it's closed then?

Answer (score 1):

The question seems ok.I am opening right now.